# Plotting several Histograms in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot several histograms in R grouping by state (UF in Brazil) because there are 27 states.

```
UFs <- unique(ENEM$SG_UF_RESIDENCIA)
View(UFs)

for(i in UFs){
  hist(ENEM$NU_NOTA_MT, main = "Histograma Nota Matemática ENEM 2017 - 2019", 
       xlab = paste("UF: ", i), ylab = "Frequência", col = "#224e69")
}
```

But when I try to run this code, nothing happens. Could someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `by`.

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(5, 6), mar=c(4, 4, 2, 2)+.1)
invisible(by(ENEM, ENEM$UFs, \(x) 
             hist(x$NU_NOTA_MT, main='', xlab=paste("UF: ", x$UFs[1]),
                  ylab='Frequência', col='#224e69')))
par(op)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
ENEM <- data.frame(NU_NOTA_MT=rnorm(2600), UFs=rep(LETTERS[1:26], each=100))
```

Comment: Are doing any grouping?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Just cosmetics, but I added new toy data to convince you ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to assign `i`to the `for`loop AND instruct R that you wish to plot several histograms at the same time (which is done using `par(mfrow = c( ,)`:

```
par(mfrow= c(2,length(unique(ENEM$SG_UF_RESIDENCIA))/2))
for(i in unique(ENEM$SG_UF_RESIDENCIA)){
  hist(ENEM[ENEM$SG_UF_RESIDENCIA == i,]$NU_NOTA_MT)
}
```

Toy data:

```
ENEM <- data.frame(
  SG_UF_RESIDENCIA = sample(LETTERS[1:6], 100, replace = TRUE),
  NU_NOTA_MT = rnorm(100)
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have your data in the long format, you can use `facet_wrap` in `ggplot2`, without loops:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>% pivot_longer(all_of(estados)) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x=value))+
        geom_histogram()+
        ylab('frequência')+
        ggtitle("Histograma Nota Matemática ENEM 2017 - 2019")+
        facet_wrap(~name)
```

[image]

**toy data**

```
estados<-c("AC", "AL", "AP", "AM", "BA", "CE", "DF", "ES", "GO", "MA", 
"MT", "MS", "MG", "PA", "PB", "PR", "PE", "PI", "RJ", "RN", "RS", 
"RO", "RR", "SC", "SP", "SE", "TO")
set.seed(1)
df <- map_dfc(estados, ~rnorm(100)) %>% set_names(estados)
```